# C++ Get Program files dir, append extra path and execute

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to write a few simple lines of code that will get the 'Program Files' dir path on both XP and Vista/7 (on vista/7 I need the path to the x86 folder), add some extra path to an application and execute it.

This is what I have so far, but it's not executing the external program, not giving an error as well..

```
wchar_t localAppData[MAX_PATH];
STARTUPINFO sInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86, 0, NULL, localAppData);

std::wstringstream ss;
ss << localAppData << L"/MyApp/MyExe.exe";
LPCWSTR str = ss.str().c_str();
CreateProcess(str, NULL,NULL, NULL,FALSE,NULL,NULL,NULL,&sInfo,&pInfo);
return str;
```

I've updated my code to this according to hmjd's suggestion:

```
wchar_t localAppData[MAX_PATH];
STARTUPINFO sInfo = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO), NULL, L"winsta0\\default" };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86, 0, NULL, localAppData);
std::wstringstream ss;
ss << localAppData << L"/PacificPoker/bin/888poker.exe";
std::wstring ss_str = ss.str();
wchar_t* path = new wchar_t[ss_str.length() + 1]();
std::copy(ss_str.begin(), ss_str.end(), path);
CreateProcess(path, NULL,NULL, NULL,FALSE,NULL,NULL,NULL,&sInfo,&pInfo);
delete[] path;
return GetLastError();
```

Still getting '3' for `GetLastError`, but I can confirm that `C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyExe.exe` exists..

Comment: How do you know it is not giving an error, there are no error checks in the posted code? Does `SHGetFolderPath()` succeed, does `CreateProcess()`, if not what does `GetLastError()` report?

Comment: @hmjd Sorry I meant that the code compiles correctly, I'll check the ``GetLastError()``

Comment: also add a breakpoint and see what's inside `localAppData`

Comment: @hmjd I changed the ``return str`` to ``return GetLastError()`` and I'm getting the value '3'.

Comment: That means `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. Updated answer.

Comment: Can you confirm that `path` contains that path by printing it?

Comment: @hmjd ``path`` returns a blank value for some reason

Comment: Check return value from `SHGetFolderPath()` and `GetLastError()`.

Comment: @hmjd ``localAppData`` also returns a blank value.. Not sure what's going on

Comment: The posted code is incorrect, create `ss_str` AFTER you have populated `ss`.

Comment: @hmjd - OK I changed the code, still getting ``GetLastError() = 3`` - updated the code in my question to reflect the updated version.

Answer (score 2):

A few problems with the code:

- `sInfo` is not initialised, you at least need to set the `cb` member

  ```
  STARTUPINFO sInfo = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO),  // 'cb'
                        NULL,                 // 'lpReserved'
                        L"winsta0\\default" };// 'lpDesktop'
  ```

See [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.

- the first argument to `CreateProcess()` should be non-const, but is being passed `c_str()` which would be a `const` **if it was not a dangling pointer**. The `ss.str()` method returns a `std::string`, and the `c_str()` is returning a pointer into that `std::string` but it is a temporary object and is destroyed at the end of the expression (the `;`), making `str` a dangling pointer. Change to:

  ```
  std::wstring ss_str = ss.str();
  wchar_t* path = new wchar_t[ss_str.length() + 1]();
  std::copy(ss_str.begin(), ss_str.end(), path);
  CreateProcess(path, ...);
  delete[] path;
  ```

Check return values of all your functions and query `GetLastError()` to determine failure reason.

Comment: Thanks hmjd, I'm very new to C++, can you please explain with a bit more details how can I solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: For background on why the command line passed in needs to be writable, see [Why does the CreateProcess function modify its input command line?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/01/9673254.aspx).

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, thanks for that link. I had occasionally wondered as to why that was.

Comment: This works! The issue was that I was using ``CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86`` instead of ``CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES`` (I'm testing on WinXP). Is there any way for me to make this code work on all Windows XP/7/Vista?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably tried this, but does `localAppData` get a valid string if you set the `CSIDL` to `CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES` instead of `CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86`?

If you're testing under XP, I don't know what `CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86` will return.